# Wrapping Entity Framework IQueryable<T> inside an action and applying the filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my first question here at Stack Overflow.

I am trying to create my own version of the repository pattern in C# with Entity Framework, and I stumbled on a problem when trying to wrap an `IQueryable<T>` within an action method like this `Action<IQueryable<T>>`. My intention is to allow specific query logic to be implemented in the repository class of each model.

Here is what I mean:

Base repository:

```
namespace Api.Domain.Repository.Base
{
    public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseTable
    {
        private readonly DataContext context;
        private readonly DbSet<T> entity;

        public Repository(DataContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            entity = context.Set<T>();
        }

        protected IList<T> Select(Action<IQueryable<T>> filter)
        {
            if (filter == null) 
               throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filter));

            var query = entity.AsQueryable<T>();
            filter(query);

            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Specific repository:

```
namespace Api.Domain.Repository
{
    public interface IAddressRepository : IRepository<Address>
    {
        IList<Address> GetMinMax(int min, int max);
    }

    public class AddressRepository : Repository<Address>, IAddressRepository
    {
        public AddressRepository(DataContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public IList<Address> GetMinMax(int min, int max)
        {
            return Select(q => q
                       .Where(a => a.Id >= min && a.Id <= max));
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine, but when I call the `GetMinMax` method, the filter (`.Where()` clause) is not applied.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong, or if this is even possible with Entity Framework?

Comment: Don't do that. Such CRUD classes are a major bad practice. EF is an ORM, a far higher-level abstraction than low level single-entity CRUDs. A DbContext isn't a connection, it's a high-level multi-entity Unit-of-Work. It doesn't need to be wrapped in CRUDs. And LINQ queries are immutable. Every operation returns a new query. You can't use an action to "modify" a query.

Comment: PS: this Select doesn't seem to Select but filter. That's what Where is for. That's the name used in SQL itself, LINQ and a *lot* of libraries. Don't change the names otherwise even *you* won't be able to understand what your code does by next Monday. Every other developer will end using the wrong methods because everything else around them uses Select to SELECT

Comment: Is'nt the Repository Pattern a CRUD on itself? i have seen it been used with entity framework countless times and i am just trying to learn how to manipulate it to create something of my own. The code i posted is not the full picture, the repository base has other methods to define what a base repo should do and what i want is to just abstract the specific queries. In this case the Select method means that it will return multiple records and when i want to apply a filter (with Where and other clauses) i want to restrict that return (just like in a real query: Select ... Where ...).

Comment: The point is that Entity Framework is a higher level abstraction than a "repository" which means those `Repository<T>` you see around are just bugs. If you want to learn how to use EF, use the official quickstarts and tutorials. You'll notice that there's no reason at all to have an `Insert` method, that `Add` or `Update` are never needed when you work with objects you loaded with EF. And that `SaveChanges` actually commits all pending changes, which means that `Repository.Insert` which contains a `SaveChanges` can execute 42 DELETEs as well - and remove your ability to roll back changes

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be like this:

```
protected IList<T> Select(Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> filter)
{
            if (filter == null) 
               throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filter));

            var query = entity.AsQueryable<T>();
            query = filter(query);

            return query.ToList();
}
```

LINQ works like decorators, filters and other operations return a new object with the filter applied. The original IQueryable is never changed.

That said, I see little advantage of doing it this way instead of exposing the IQueryable and having the MinMax method do `GetQuery().Where(a => a.Id >= min && a.Id <= max).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks good sir, that did the trick. I know i can expose the Queryable component, but what i really want is to mimic something that i think is interesting from another ORM framework called NHibernate. The idea is to mimic the IQueryOver<> and the its FluentAPI to query the db. I know it might be old but i think when implemented right it can be helpful in creating clean code and segregating query logic from the business classes.